# Strange files on FTP account

Tags: security, ftp

We have a user who needs to use FTP for a specific application.  For the last wee or so, really starnge files have been appearing in their account:

```
-rw------- 1 root       root          59 Nov 21 14:59 WZOBLx
-rw------- 1 root       root         108 Nov 21 14:59 x5yOLt
-rw------- 1 root       root          63 Nov 21 14:59 XcwBDS
```

They are all of the same format.  The individual files cannot be moved copied or deleted - eg

```
rm: cannot remove 'WZOBLx': No such file or director
```

I am assuming that the server has been compromised in some way (running proftp)?   Any suggestions (other than not to use ftp!_

Comment: Check your `ftp` logs. Use  `ls -b` to check for non-printing characters in the filenames. the `(root,root)` ownership is worrisome. Does your `ftp` user get logged in as `root`? If so, you have bigger problems.

Comment: No the user does not get logged in as root and in fact get chroot jailed.  ls -b is a good idea..

Comment: no - non printing characters.  The home directories are on an nfs share so I guess their could be an nfs issue?  ssh was also enabled - shutdown now